# C# winforms how to set padding for checkboxes in checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

In the above diagram ,I want to  set padding (to RIGHT) for the check boxes in checkedlistbox.

Comment: As in increase the gap between the checkbox and the text?

Comment: Just increase the width of the the control, that's it!

Comment: @Pawan: look at the tags. It's winforms. The CheckBoxes are not individual controls.

Comment: I know it is `winforms` and `CheckedListBox` is a winform control. I asked you to increase the width of the whole control not individual checkbox, it will automatically starts giving you padding on the right when you increase the width.

Comment: @Pawan: ok, but: no, it will not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple workaround to get your desired result, since there is no built-in Functionality for that:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckedListBox chkList = new CheckedListBox();
    chkList.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    chkList.Margin = new Padding(20, 3, 3, 3);
    chkList.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" });
    FlowLayoutPanel fPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    fPanel.Height = this.Height;
    chkList.BackColor = fPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
    fPanel.Controls.Add(chkList);

    this.Controls.Add(fPanel);
}
```

Feel free to do the same approach using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckedListBox` does not provide that function (as far as I see).
The only quick solution that I could think of is to simply add 2-3 spaces before every item text. This is 'dirty' but it would work.
Other than that, you could only use something different like a `DataGridView`.